How to create specific version GKE cluster master and nodepool using Terraform
I am trying to crate GKE cluster with specific version but it's not working. Please can some one help which option/flag need to use to create specific version.
I have tried the following option under
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name     = "my-gke-cluster"
  location = "us-central1"
  initial_node_count       = 1
  master_version = '1.28.7-gke.1026000' // Here I have tried `min_master_version` flag also
}

Also in node pool:
resource "google_container_node_pool" "primary_preemptible_nodes" {
  name       = "my-node-pool"
  location   = "us-central1"
  cluster    = google_container_cluster.primary.name
  node_count = 1
  version = '1.28.7-gke.1026000'
}


What exactly is not working? Is there any error message? Please edit your post and add more details.

It's creating the cluster but it's taking default version rather than specific version in tf script

Check the node_version property. Also, see google_container_engine_versions

getting node_version supported argument
